# Optimizing the width of a div with a fixed height? (i.e. smallest width that will still fit the text)

Tags: javascript, html, layout, height, fixed

I have a div that contains a variable amount of text, and a fixed height. Without a fixed width, the width would automatically be 100%. I could estimate the width that the div would need to be, but since the text will not always be the same, this will not always work. It would need to automatically be determined each time. Basically, I want the width of the div to be determined by the content.

Simply, my div would be something like

```
#a {
height:100px;
width:?;
}
```

Consider these: http://jsfiddle.net/ZE4Sy/2/

This is essentially what my goal is (though I did this by estimating the widths). Each div has a fixed height, but a different amount of text. I made the widths as small as they could be before the text began exceeding the height.

I only have a very basic knowledge of jquery/javascript, but I'm assuming that if there is a solution to this, it may involve those.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In your demo, the text overflows in all of them in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('.box').each(function () { 
    var $box = $(this),
        width = $box.width(),
        $inner = $box.wrapInner('<div></div>').children().first();

    while (width > 0 && $inner.height() < $box.height()) $box.width(--width);  
    $box.width(++width);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZE4Sy/6/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in my case there were two factors that prevented Šime Vidas' solution from working, which were that the content in my div contained HTML (p tags with margins, etc), and I wanted the div to protrude outside of the available width of the containing div if necessary. Using his solution for inspiration, I came up with this:

```
$('.box').each(function () { 
    $box = $(this);
    $inner = $box.wrapInner('<div></div>');
    while ($inner[0].scrollHeight > $box.height()) $box.width($box.width()+100);  
});
```

Which simply keeps widening the box a little until the height of the inner div doesn't overrun the containing one. You could reduce the +100 figure to get a more accurate width, at the expense of processing time.